# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined.

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-elements

Developers,

HELP. I'm getting this error with the below, I've been pouring over it trying to find the issue but just can't see it! What's wrong here? It seems to be stemming from the code from 146 to 236.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in >components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: >undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's >defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  LayoutAnimation,
  UIManager,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { Button, Input } from "react-native-elements";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import SimpleIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons";

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

// Enable LayoutAnimation on Android
UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);

const TabSelector = ({ selected }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.selectorContainer}>
      <View style={selected && styles.selected} />
    </View>
  );
};

TabSelector.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default class AuthScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      selectedCategory: 0,
      isLoading: false,
      isPasswordValid: true,
      isConfirmationValid: true
    };

    this.selectCategory = this.selectCategory.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this);
  }

  selectCategory(selectedCategory) {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
    this.setState({
      selectedCategory,
      isLoading: false
    });
  }

  login() {
    const { password } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    // Simulate an API call
    setTimeout(() => {
      LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        isPasswordValid: password.length >= 8 || this.passwordInput.shake()
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  signUp() {
    const { password, passwordConfirmation } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    // Simulate an API call
    setTimeout(() => {
      LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        isPasswordValid: password.length >= 8 || this.passwordInput.shake(),
        isConfirmationValid:
          password == passwordConfirmation || this.confirmationInput.shake()
      });
    }, 1500);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      selectedCategory,
      isLoading,
      isPasswordValid,
      isConfirmationValid,
      email,
      password,
      passwordConfirmation
    } = this.state;
    const isLoginPage = selectedCategory === 0;
    const isSignUpPage = selectedCategory === 1;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.loginContainer}
          behavior="position"
        >
          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
              <Text style={styles.titleText}>BEAUX</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ marginTop: -10, marginLeft: 10 }}>
              <Text style={styles.titleText}>VOYAGES</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Button
              disabled={isLoading}
              clear
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              onPress={() => this.selectCategory(0)}
              containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
              titleStyle={[
                styles.categoryText,
                isLoginPage && styles.selectedCategoryText
              ]}
              title={"Login"}
            />
            <Button
              disabled={isLoading}
              clear
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              onPress={() => this.selectCategory(1)}
              containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
              titleStyle={[
                styles.categoryText,
                isSignUpPage && styles.selectedCategoryText
              ]}
              title={"Sign up"}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.rowSelector}>
            <TabSelector selected={isLoginPage} />
            <TabSelector selected={isSignUpPage} />
          </View>
          {/* //!ISSUE LIES HERE */}
          <View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <Input
              leftIcon={
                <Icon
                  name="envelope-o"
                  color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
                  size={25}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                />
              }
              value={email}
              keyboardAppearance="light"
              autoFocus={false}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              keyboardType="email-address"
              returnKeyType="next"
              inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
              placeholder={"Email"}
              containerStyle={{
                borderBottomColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
              }}
          ref={input => (this.emailInput = input)}
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
        />
        <Input
          leftIcon={
            <SimpleIcon
              name="lock"
              color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
              size={25}
              style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
            />
          }
          value={password}
          keyboardAppearance="light"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          returnKeyType={isSignUpPage ? "next" : "done"}
          blurOnSubmit={true}
          containerStyle={{
            marginTop: 16,
            borderBottomColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
          }}
          inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
          placeholder={"Password"}
          ref={input => (this.passwordInput = input)}
          onSubmitEditing={() =>
            isSignUpPage ? this.confirmationInput.focus() : this.login()
          }
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          errorMessage={
            isPasswordValid ? null : "Please enter at least 8 characters"
          }
        />
        {isSignUpPage && (
          <Input
            icon={
              <SimpleIcon
                name="lock"
                color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
                size={25}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
              />
            }
            value={passwordConfirmation}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            keyboardAppearance="light"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            keyboardType="default"
            returnKeyType={"done"}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            containerStyle={{
              marginTop: 16,
              borderBottomColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
            }}
            inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
            placeholder={"Confirm password"}
            ref={input => (this.confirmationInput = input)}
            onSubmitEditing={this.signUp}
            onChangeText={passwordConfirmation =>
              this.setState({ passwordConfirmation })
            }
            errorMessage={
              isConfirmationValid ? null : "Please enter the same password"
            }
          />
        )}
        {/* //!ISSUE ENDS HERE */}
        <Button
          buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
          containerStyle={{ marginTop: 32, flex: 0 }}
          activeOpacity={0.8}
          title={isLoginPage ? "LOGIN" : "SIGN UP"}
          onPress={isLoginPage ? this.login : this.signUp}
          titleStyle={styles.loginTextButton}
          loading={isLoading}
          disabled={isLoading}
        />
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
      <Button
        title={"Need help ?"}
        titleStyle={{ color: "red" }}
        buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
        underlayColor="transparent"
        onPress={() => console.log("Account created")}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#034d84",
    flex: 1
  },
  rowSelector: {
    height: 20,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  selectorContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  selected: {
    position: "absolute",
    borderRadius: 50,
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    top: -5,
    borderRightWidth: 70,
    borderBottomWidth: 70,
    borderColor: "white",
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  loginContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  loginTextButton: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(232, 147, 142, 1)",
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 50,
    width: 200
  },
  titleContainer: {
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  formContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 30,
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingTop: 32,
    paddingBottom: 32,
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  loginText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white"
  },
  categoryText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: "light",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    opacity: 0.54
  },
  selectedCategoryText: {
    opacity: 1
  },
  titleText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: "regular"
  },
  helpContainer: {
    height: 64,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Comment: Try commenting out the icon props on your 3 Input elements, there might be something wrong there. Also: there is one Input where you set a non-existing icon prop (instead of leftIcon)

Comment: Thanks, good spot on the leftIcon or lack of must have looked over this 1000 times and not see that. Issue still remains though even when commenting out the icon props, seems to be the inputs that are causing the issue

Comment: Alright, let's keep digging then ;-) Which version of the elements library are you running?

Comment: Current versions are: "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input that you are on react-native-elements version 0.19.1, it seems the Input component isn't available ([see docs](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/overview.html)). Only the v1.0.0 beta versions support Input as component.

Comment: That would explain it! Really appreciate your help with this, it always turns out to be something so simple

Comment: Glad I could help!